# How to round a large decimal value in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying in the following code to round a decimal number based on the decimal format that I set at the beginning:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000"); 
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

double a = Double.parseDouble(df.format(43.473684210526315));
double b = Math.pow(a, 10);
double c = Double.parseDouble(df.format(b));

System.out.println(a + " ** " + b  +  " ** " + c);
```

The result that I got is:

```
43.473 ** 2.4109939006965688E16 ** 2.4109939006965688E16
```

As you see, the value of `a` is formatted properly. While the other values are not. After spending a long time trying to understand what is going on, I found out the value `2.4109939006965688E16` can not be formatted. I tested the same value after removing `E16` and it worked.

My question is how can I round such a large decimal so that it works as the `a`?

Comment: Are you aware what E16 means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pure luck that `a` works. If the initial value was `43.4701` you would be seeing `43.47`. And in some cases you would see more than 3 decimal places due to the inaccuracy of `double`.

You only use the DecimalFormatter to create a `String` briefly before turning back into a `double` again. You want to keep and use that string.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");

double b = Math.pow(43.473684210526315, 10);

String bFormatted = df.format(b);

System.out.println(bFormatted);
```

Gives you your desired output `24115485538109308.000`

Answer (score 1):

For your "big" decimals you can use the following format:

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.000E0");
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues here:

- You do not specify a locale for your DecimalFormat. So the combination of `DecimalFormat.format` and `Double.parseDouble` is error prone, as e.g. with german locale, `DecimalFormat.format` will use a comma as decimal separator, which is unsupported by `Double.parseDouble`, and will throw a `NumberFormatException`. You should use both `format` and `parse` of your DecimalFormat.
- Also, you use your double values directly for `System.out.println`. Why not concatenating the results of `DecimalFormat.format`, to achieve exactly what you want? E.g. `System.out.println(df.format(a) + " ** " + df.format(b) + " ** " + df.format(c));`
- If you want to do real mathematical rounding (e.g. needing the double value for additional calculations), use `Math.round`. You can multiply and divide by 10, 100, 1000 etc. to achieve the desired precision. Note that, with the `double` data type, you can't do **exact** rounding.

Answer (score 1):

For large numbers, you'll need to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(43.473);
BigDecimal b = a.pow(10);

System.out.println(df.format(a) + " ** " + b.doubleValue() + " ** " + df.format(b));
```

This results in the following output

```
43.472 ** 2.4109939006965688E16 ** 24109939006965686.655
```